# Replace leading period (".") in list of pathname strings + R

Tags: r, regex, string, list, replace

I need to replace the first period (".") in a list of pathname strings, I know I should be able to do this with regex but can't find a good example.

Here is an example of the pathnames:

```
paths <- c("/Users/user/Study/data/ARaw_Sequences/16S_raw_sequences/RemovePrimer_Final.274571-3-2022_1.fq.gz", 
"/Users/user/Documents/R/Study/data/Raw_Sequences/16S_raw_sequences/RemovePrimer_Final.274575-15-2022_1.fq.gz")
```

I need to replace the period between `Final` and the id code `27...` so it ends up like this -

```
RemovePrimer_Final_274575-15-2022_1.fq.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basename()` will return the filename from your filepaths and we can use `sub()` to only replace the first '.' character.

```r
paths <- c("/Users/user/Study/data/ARaw_Sequences/16S_raw_sequences/RemovePrimer_Final.274571-3-2022_1.fq.gz", 
           "/Users/user/Documents/R/Study/data/Raw_Sequences/16S_raw_sequences/RemovePrimer_Final.274575-15-2022_1.fq.gz")

sub("\\.", "_", basename(paths))
#> [1] "RemovePrimer_Final_274571-3-2022_1.fq.gz" 
#> [2] "RemovePrimer_Final_274575-15-2022_1.fq.gz"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

*edit* Removing the `basename()` will replace '.' with '_' in the full path.

```r
paths <- c("/Users/user/Study/data/ARaw_Sequences/16S_raw_sequences/RemovePrimer_Final.274571-3-2022_1.fq.gz", 
           "/Users/user/Documents/R/Study/data/Raw_Sequences/16S_raw_sequences/RemovePrimer_Final.274575-15-2022_1.fq.gz")

sub("\\.", "_", paths)
#> [1] "/Users/user/Study/data/ARaw_Sequences/16S_raw_sequences/RemovePrimer_Final_274571-3-2022_1.fq.gz"            
#> [2] "/Users/user/Documents/R/Study/data/Raw_Sequences/16S_raw_sequences/RemovePrimer_Final_274575-15-2022_1.fq.gz"
```

The double slashes are required so R looks for a `.` character. Otherwise a regex with "." will match any character. The backslashes let us escape this matching and returns the explicit match we want.

Comment: Thanks! What's the purpose of the leading double backslash "\\"?

Comment: I still need a version with the full pathname though.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the output you were aiming for. I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I see how that could have been confusing.